# Default list search, columns scope

Tags: 2013, list, web-part, search, search-results

Is it possible in SP13 to set the **search fields (columns)** for the default SharePoint **list search** (in the view list page).

I would like to search only in a few columns (avoid Authors etc.).

[image: Default List Search]

Answer (score 0):

Indexing your list columns will allow you to search on the columns that you want to display results on. Go to List Settings -- (under the columns section) click on Indexed columns.

[image]

Create a new index on the column(s) you would like to search on. For example my list search box will first look for results on "Case Name" then "Case Number" AND then "CU Name".

[image]
Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: The search is still executed on all the columns of the list.

Comment: Make sure to run "Start Incremental Crawl" on the Search Application to pickup the changes. Sorry I failed to mention that. Check out this link... http://www.kwizcom.com/ContentPage.asp?PageId=1156

Comment: Not working still after an Incremental Crawl. It is searching in all the columnd of the library.

Comment: Its a library and not a list...ok What columns are you trying to search on?

Comment: Sorry, it is a custom list, and I want to search on some custom fields

Comment: Indexing the columns and running a crawl should do the trick. Before we try anything else, try running a "Full Crawl" and see if that makes a difference. In some cases this is the solution.

Comment: I tried but still not working :/